# How do I prevent Office applications to update one of my SPListItem properties?

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, office-integration

I have a document library in SharePoint whith a custom content type. There is one custom field that is set by an item added event receiver each time a new document is uploaded.

My problem occurs when someone opens a document with Word and uses the "save as" option in the Word menu to save a new document. My event receiver sets the correct value to my field and then Word is setting the field back to the old value again.

How can I prevent Word from changing my field ? The field is hidden, readonly and sealed.

Comment: I think I can catch the item updating event fired by Word. If there is a way to know that it is Word trying to change my item I could cancel the event. How do I find out if it is Word?